# why integration of $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\arctan(x)+c$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I manually integrated $$\int  \frac {dx}{x^2+1}$$
 using u substitution and I got $$\frac {\ln(1+x^2)}{2x}$$
 where did I go wrong?

[u substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EApz6.png)

Comment: In your u-sub you treat the $x$ in the differential as a constant which you have put upfront the new integral. You cannot do that. The $x$ has to disappear through your substitution

Comment: Take the deriative of your "answer" and of $\arctan x$ and see why. Further, a change of variable isn't wise because the derivative of $1 + x^2$ doesn't appear in the integeand.

Comment: @imranfat im so bad at basic calculus, can you give me some book recommendations so that i can learn fundamental calculus and do you have any suggestions of any other material?

Comment: To really show you where you went wrong, it would help to see every single step you took between $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$ and $\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{2x}$. But one guess is that you treated $\frac{1}{2x}$ as a constant with respect to $u$ after the substitution. And that would be incorrect.

Comment: @GenghisKanna There are many good intro calculus books on the market. Stewart Calculus is a good one to study from, but that is just my opinion. You can get an outdated version for little money.

Answer (score 4):

$x$ depends on $u$ hence you have to express $x$ as a function of $u$.

However, if $g=f^{-1}$ then
$$
g'(y)=\frac{1}{f'\left(g\left(y\right)\right)}
$$
With $f=\tan$ then
$$
\text{arctan}'\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{\tan'\left(\text{arctan}\left(y\right)\right)}
$$
Using that $\tan'\left(x\right)=1+\tan^2(x)$ we have
$$
\text{arctan}'\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{1+\tan\left(\text{arctan}\left(y\right)\right)}=\frac{1}{1+y^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't take the $\frac{1}{2x}$ out of the integral. That only works with constants.

Answer (score 0):

As you know an indefinite integral such as $\int  \frac {dx}{1+x^2}$ is an antiderivative.

Since $$ \frac {d}{dx} \tan ^{-1}x = \frac {1}{1+x^2}$$ we have          $$\int  \frac {dx}{1+x^2}= tan ^{-1}x +C$$

Back to your work,

$$u= 1+x^2, du= 2x dx, dx = \frac {du}{2x}$$

$$\int  \frac {dx}{1+x^2}=  \int  \frac {du}{u(2x)}=???  $$

What did you do with the $(2x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put outside the integral the $1/2x$
$$I=\int  \frac {dx}{1+x^2}$$
$$ \text {for this substitution } u=x^2+1 \implies du=2xdx$$
Then
$$I=\int  \frac {dx}{1+x^2}=\int  \frac {du}{2xu}$$
You cant go further...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, after u-substitution, then$$\int du\,\frac {2x}u\neq\frac {\log u}{2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that you wrote down $u=1+x^2$ in the first place, so you can't just pull $\frac{1}{2x}$ out.

Sometimes it's hard to evaluate integrals. Therefore, there have been ways and methods to solve them. I think you need trigonometric substitution. See [Tri-sub on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Integrals_containing_a2_+_x2). Just replace $a$ with $1$.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the result indirectly through the chain rule, as follows:

Let y = arctanx. Then tany = x. Differentiate w/r to x: you get dy/dx = the square of cosy. But cosy = 1/[sq. root of(1+x-squared]) ....[To see this, draw a right triangle with legs 1 and x as the adjacent sides of angle y (to conform to the condition that tany=x)]. Thus we have dy/dx=1/(1+x-squared), i.e. 
d(arctanx)/dx=1/(1+x-squared), hence arctanx = the integral (antiderivative) of 
1/(1+x-squared).